# Updated Post. Fetching a Json with Websocket and display on the screen the values

Tags: flutter, dart

On the console i can see the Json arriving as follows if i print it out
{"cyclus":9,"range":1.681231022,"force":20.81800461}

Now i am not re-declaring the jsondat and used your approach.
If i print out the values i can see them on the console like this.

flutter: 20.84395218
flutter: 1.609025955

If i  comment //range = jsondat["force"]; and comment //force = jsondat["force"];  ....connected becomes true and on the console i see both values.

If i uncomment range = jsondat["force"]; and force = jsondat["force"]; i get on the console stuff like that.

#38     _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1335:19)
#39     _CustomZone.runUnaryGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:1244:7)
#40     _BufferingStreamSubscription._sendData (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:341:11)
#41     _BufferingStreamSubscription._add (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:271:7)
#42     _SyncStreamControllerDispatch._sendData (dart:async/stream_controller.dart:774:19)

```
          setState(() {
           if (jsondat.isNotEmpty){
              connected = true;
              print(jsondat["range"]);
              print(jsondat["force"]);
              //range = jsondat["force"];
              //force = jsondat["force"];
            }
          });
```

Follows the code. Thanks in advance for some help

```
// ignore_for_file: avoid_print

import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:web_socket_channel/io.dart';
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:io';

const String fileName = 'myJsonFile.json';

void main() => runApp(const MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: WebSocketPOTY(),
    );
  }
}

//apply this class on home: attribute at MaterialApp()
class WebSocketPOTY extends StatefulWidget {
  const WebSocketPOTY({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return _WebSocketDHT();
  }
}

class _WebSocketDHT extends State<WebSocketPOTY> {
  String range = "0";
  String force = "0";

  late IOWebSocketChannel channel;
  late bool connected; //boolean value to track if WebSocket is connected

  late File _filePath;

  Future<String> get _localPath async {
    final directory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    return directory.path;
  }

  Future<File> get _localFile async {
    final path = await _localPath;
    return File('$path/$fileName');
  }

  void _readJson() async {
    _filePath = await _localFile;
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    _readJson();
    connected = false;

    Future.delayed(Duration.zero, () async {
      channelconnect();
    });

    super.initState();
  }

  channelconnect() {
    try {
      channel = IOWebSocketChannel.connect("ws://192.168.1.100:80");
      channel.stream.listen(
        (message) {
          //print(message);
          Map<String, dynamic> jsondat = jsonDecode(message);
          //String data = jsonEncode(jsondat);
          _filePath.writeAsString(message);

          setState(() {
           if (jsondat.isNotEmpty){
              connected = true;
              print(jsondat["range"]);
              print(jsondat["force"]);
              //range = (jsondat["force"]);
              //force = jsondat["force"];
            }
          });
        },
        onDone: () {
          //if WebSocket is disconnected
          print("Web socket is closed");
          setState(() {
            connected = false;
          });
        },
        onError: (error) {
          print(error.toString());
        },
      );
    } catch (_) {
      print("error on connecting to websocket.");
    }
  }

  Future<void> sendcmd(String cmd) async {
    if (connected == true) {
      channel.sink.add(cmd); //sending Command to NodeMCU
      //send command to NodeMCU
    } else {
      channelconnect();
      print("Websocket is not connected.");
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text("Poty"),
          backgroundColor: const Color.fromARGB(255, 30, 89, 106)),
      body: Container(
          alignment: Alignment.topCenter, //inner widget alignment to center
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
          child: Column(
            children: [
              Container(
                  //showing if websocket is connected or disconnected
                  child: connected
                      ? const Text(
                          "WEBSOCKET: CONNECTED",
                          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18),
                        )
                      : const Text(
                          "DISCONNECTED",
                          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18),
                        )),
              const SizedBox(
                height: 50,
              ),
              Text(
                "$range Milimeter",
                style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 18),
              ),
              const SizedBox(
                height: 20,
              ),
              Text(
                " $force Newton",
                style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 18),
              ),
            ],
          )),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, why are you re-declaring `jsondat`?

Secondly, your json data `{"cyclus":29,"range":50,"force":15.25071}` contains `cyclus` which means your `else if` will never execute.

```
      channel.stream.listen(
        (message) {
          print(message);
          Map<String, dynamic> jsondat = jsonDecode(message); // Here
          String data = jsonEncode(jsondat);
          _filePath.writeAsString(data);

          setState(() {
            if (jsondat.containsKey('cyclus')) {
              connected = true;
            } else if (jsondat.containsKey('range')) {
              Map<String, dynamic> jsondat = json.decode(message); // and Here
              setState(() {
                range = jsondat['range'];
                force = jsondat['force'];
                //_filePath.writeAsString(message);
              });
            }
          });
        },
```

Refactor it to be

```
channel = IOWebSocketChannel.connect("ws://192.168.0.254:80");
      channel.stream.listen(
        (message) {
          print(message);
          Map<String, dynamic> jsondat = jsonDecode(message);
          String data = jsonEncode(jsondat);
          _filePath.writeAsString(data);

          setState(() {
            if (jsondat.isNotEmpty) { // Or whatever method/technique you choose
              connected = true;
              range = jsondat['range'];
              force = jsondat['force'];
              //_filePath.writeAsString(message);
            }
          });
        },
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply: I refactored it. Like this it does not work and at the console i am not able to see the Json. I get stuff like this . #53     _StreamController.add (dart:async/stream_controller.dart:596:5)
#54     new _RawSocket.<anonymous closure> (dart:io-patch/socket_patch.dart:1839:33)
#55     _NativeSocket.issueReadEvent.issue (dart:io-patch/socket_patch.dart:1322:14)
#56     _microtaskLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:40:21)
#57     _startMicrotaskLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:49:5)

Comment: If i print the values. I get the correct values.             if (jsondat.containsKey("cyclus")) {
              connected = true;
              print(jsondat["range"]);
              print(jsondat["force"]);
              //range = jsondat["range"];
              //force = jsondat["force"];
            }

Comment: I think the problem right now lies here.               range = jsondat["range"];
              force = jsondat["force"];

Comment: Isn't your first comment a different issue? What is range and force returning, string or int? Please update your post with the new error message.